# Как проскроллить до низу элемент в средине списка

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Есть RecyclerView  в котором во View-ху в средине списка я добавляю дочерние View-ху, при это мне нужно видить последнюю добавленную View в конкретном item'e.
Пробовал сделать так:

```
linearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(recyclerViewAdapter.currentQuestionPosition,-50);
```

Так я могу подтягивать нужный элемент вверх, указывая отрицательное значение, но как мне эту величину подставлять туда динамически в зависимости от того насколько увеличился элемент